# How to get which pagination is getting navigated to another page if two paginations in one page view Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have recently built some admin dashboard for managing projects and blog posts together. I wanted to put both in one dashboard and show as two tables with pagination. So in controller, I put something like this:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'Project'=>array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array(
                'Project.created_time' => 'desc'
            ),
            'paramType' => 'querystring'
        ),
        'Post'=>array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array(
                'Post.created_time' => 'desc'
            ),
            'paramType' => 'querystring'
        )
    );
    $projects = $this->Paginator->paginate('Project');

    $posts = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post');
    $this->set('projects', $projects);

    $this->set('posts', $posts);
```

and in the view I use

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model'=>'Post')); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model'=>'Project')); ?>
```

to manage the pages link of each model.
But the problem is when I click one page link, the other one is changing to that page as well. The url only give the paged link as `dashboard?page=5`

Is there anyway that I can access them separately? Like `dashboard?project_page=5` or`dashboard?post_page=5`.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Paginator is not designed to have more than one on a page.  The only solution I can think is to make the contents of the two paginated lists on two completely separate pages from the one you are creating now, then use Javascript and Ajax to pull the contents of each paginated list when the user attempts to navigate to different pages on each list.

Comment: But at what about the `public $paginate` in controller? in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html it can be used for multiple paginations

Comment: As I said, Paginator component and helper aren't really designed to work with multiple on the same page, which is why you're having these problems.  Yes, multiple on the same page will partway work, but ultimately they'll end up interfering with each other.  There's resources on the internet where people did exactly what I was talking about to get around it, such as:  http://deadlytechnology.com/php/paginate-multiple-data-sets/